# Apply Grid Shift Transform file to GeoServer

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver

Trying to apply a grid shift file to GeoServer.  Have looked at the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#add-grid-shift-transform-files) but all it seems to say is to put the files in the `user_projections`, which I've done.

I'm trying to use `OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb` to convert EPSG:27700 to EPSG:3857.  I've downloaded the NTv2 grid files and added to the  `user_projections` folder, however it doesn't seem to have any affect when testing in the [Reprojection console](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#reprojection-console).

How do I '*make*' GeoServer use the more accurate grid shift?

Answer (score 1):

All I can say is it works on my machine - I added `ISTN02_NTv2.gsb` to `data/user_projections`. Restarted GeoServer (not sure if it is necessary but never hurts) and now I see this in the reprojection tool.

[image]

### Update

I downloaded the [`OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb` file](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj-datumgrid/blob/master/europe/OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb) and added it to `data/user_projections` too. Now when I look at the transformation in the reprojection tool I see:

[image]

Are you sure that the tomcat user can read the file?

```
➜  user_projections  ls -l
total 68856
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat8 tomcat8    12905 Jan 13  2017 epsg.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    15240384 Feb 25  2019 OSTN02_NTv2.gsb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root         432 Feb 25  2019 OSTN02_NTv2_Header.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    40005491 Feb 25  2019 OSTN02_NTv2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    15240384 Feb 25 17:13 OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb
```

(Oh, and you don't need to restart GeoServer for it to take effect)

Comment: Does it make a difference as I'm trying to use the ```OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb``` and not the ```OSTN02_NTv2.gsb``` in your example @Ian?

Comment: Just tried with the ```OSTN02_NTv2.gsb``` file and I get same results as you @Ian, so am I asking the wrong question?  Trying to use the newer more accurate grid shift from the [OS](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/for-developers)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ian, downloaded the same file you linked to (in case I had a duff version), put both files (OSTN02 & OSTN15) in folder with same permissions, console references OSTN02  version.  Remove the OSTN02 file and doesn't pick up the OSTN15.  Anything else you can think to check?

Comment: can you check the log and see if there is anything there that indicates it can't find the file, a search for 'NTv2' should find them

Comment: Nothing in the logs @Ian.  Absolutely baffled .

Comment: Are you on windows or linux? can you see any difference in permissions between the two files?failing that attach a debugger and watch