# Different polygon placement between GeoServer versions for the same data

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, postgresql, azure

I have a database with a table containing 27700 geometry polygons on an Azure managed Postgres database.

I've also got two GeoServer instances with layers created from that same table, but on one of these servers the geometry is a yard or two misaligned.

One of the servers (the misaligned one) is running GeoServer 2.20.4 on an Azure VM.
The other that aligns correctly is running GeoServer 2.16.0 on a non-Azure third party VM.

I have checked the layers and every setting I can see is the same apart from the lat/long bounding box...when I compute it I get different results even though they point to the same data:

Misaligned instance:
-9.30951997270238 49.766807272578696    2.688180228215253   60.7700088415435

Correct instance:
-9.308765550924253  49.76680681042395   2.690697575377409   60.77002485806145

Both layers are set to native 27700.
But are called with srs=EPSG:3857.

Could it be that the two servers are working to a different algorithm when converting to 3857? If so, does anyone know where this setting or algorithm can be accessed and changed?

Comment: did you may be add the NTv2 grids on one and not the other?

Comment: No, 'NTv2 grids' is new to me, I will google it and give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/for-developers

Comment: also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388301/apply-grid-shift-transform-file-to-geoserver

Comment: Thankyou, that did it. Much appreciated.