Difference in transforming from ETRS89 to DHDN (25832 to 31467)
I'm in trouble as I can't get the same result by converting from EPSG:25832 (ETRS89/UTM32N) to EPSG:31467 (DHDN/3-degree Gauss-Krüger Zone 3) using GeoServer and for example https://epsg.io (https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=25832&t_srs=31467&x=672228.2210000&y=5722243.0450000 )
With epsg.io I get 3672370.361 5724094.278 and with GeoServer it is 3672371.57465833 5724093.783763679
I have already placed BETA2007.gsb in my user_projections directory but I am still getting incorrect coordinates. Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Turn the logging up to GEOTOOLS-DEV and try again, this should tell you if the transform is being picked up correctly

See if https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/388301/79 helps

Unfortunately that MapTiler service at epsg.io does not show what transformation it is really using. I recommend using the Projinfo utility projinfo -s epsg:25832 -t epsg:31467 for finding out the exact parameters, and testing the transformation with cs2cs https://proj.org/en/9.4/apps/cs2cs.html. Just for being sure about what really happens.
